# how to concatenate string from query sql server 2005 but datatype is integer

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

```
(WATCHDOGACIDT.COMASCALEE + WATCHDOGACIDT.COMASCALEV + 
                      WATCHDOGACIDT.COMASCALEM) AS EVM           --not work

(PATIENT_NAME.FIRSTNAME +' '+ PATIENT_NAME.LASTNAME) AS Fullname --work great
```

but this code return summary

ex 1 + 2 + 3 i would like return 123 but return 6 thank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
CAST(myIntegerVar AS varchar(50)) + ' some text etc'
```

so:

```
(CAST(WATCHDOGACIDT.COMASCALEE as varchar(1)) + CAST(WATCHDOGACIDT.COMASCALEV AS varchar(1)) + CAST(WATCHDOGACIDT.COMASCALEM AS varchar(1)) ) AS EVM
```

Answer (score 1):

Mitch's answer has the right approach, but in case you don't always know the length of the value you are casting to a varchar you don't need to specify the length.  i.e. if one of your numbers was 450 or something, the varchar(1) wouldn't do the trick.

Like this:

```
CAST(myIntegerVar AS varchar) + ' some text etc'

(CAST(WATCHDOGACIDT.COMASCALEE as varchar) + CAST(WATCHDOGACIDT.COMASCALEV AS varchar) + CAST(WATCHDOGACIDT.COMASCALEM AS varchar) ) AS EVM
```